# Securing a folder and redirecting it to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Trying to secure a folder with .htaccess
First I want all requests to that folder to redirect to https then to ask the user for a password.

My .htaccess file that's in the root of the protected folder looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

AuthUserFile "/etc/somewhere/.htpasswd"
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
require valid-user
```

I get asked for a password - but the https redirection does not work
So if I try www.domain.com/folder the auth box comes up with user/pass request but it stays in http... I want it to first go into https mode then ask for a password.

Ay reason why this is not working ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking at a cached resource?

Comment: Ii am trying from icognito as well as new browser instances. It simply does not redirect to SSL. Very very annoying as this really should be a common thing people would want to do all the time with their protected folders.

Comment: What does your browser's network console say? Do you see the redirection in there?